# Single contact showing in Sitecore Experience Profile

Tags: xdb, experience-profile, xconnect

I've created an xConnect client API for Sitecore 9 that creates new contacts and sets the facet properties. I've added multiple contacts to xDB, however only one contact has shown in the Experience Profile search so far. I've tried adding a known contact and an anonymous one, but without any luck. When I look up the guid of the contact and enter it manually in the URL it does redirect to that contact, but that same contact does not appear in the Experience Profile search. I've also tried rebuilding the reporting database and rebuilding the search index. So far nothing seemed to help. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

I create a contact like this:

```
var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[]
{
    new ContactIdentifier(source, id, ContactIdentifierType.Known),
};
var xContact = new Contact(identifiers);

client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(xContact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfoFacet);

client.AddContact(xContact);
client.Submit();
```

I create an interaction like this:

```
var interaction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, Guid.Parse(channelId), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_AGENT"]);
Event ev = new Event(Guid.Parse(eventId), DateTime.UtcNow) { };
interaction.Events.Add(ev);
client.AddInteraction(interaction);
client.Submit();
```

Comment: The code looks fine, are you sure the existingContact is the contact you expect it to be?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: How do you get the existingContact, are you sure you're not getting the Contact you do see in the experience profile everytime

Comment: I'm sure, because when I retrieve the guid of the new contact, and add the GUID to the url, so ExperienceProfile/contact?cid={GUID}, it returns the correct contact with the interactions and events.

Comment: The contact gets added correctly in xDB with all its facets. However it doesn't show up in the experience profile search.

Comment: welp i'm at a loss, sorry keep me up to date if you find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rebuilding the reporting database and rebuilding the search indexer, I found that the 'Sitecore xConnect Search Indexer' service was't running in Windows services. After starting the service, the contacts started showing up in the experience profile.

Answer (score 2):

In the initial release of Sitecore 9 the experience profile had some issues.
The 'To date' in the filter wasn't working properly.
I've added a screenshot of all known issues, these are fixed in Sitecore 9 update 1!

[image]

Comment: I'm already running on update 1 of Sitecore 9

Comment: can you share the code of how you create the new Contacts and fill their facets?

Comment: I add a contact like this:var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[]
 {
  new ContactIdentifier(source, id, ContactIdentifierType.Known),
 };
var xContact = new Contact(identifiers);

client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(xContact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfoFacet);

client.AddContact(xContact);
client.Submit();

Comment: I add an interaction like this: var interaction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, Guid.Parse(channelId), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_AGENT"]);
Event ev = new Event(Guid.Parse(eventId), DateTime.UtcNow) { };
interaction.Events.Add(ev);
client.AddInteraction(interaction);
client.Submit();

Comment: Could you add the code in your post, makes it alot more readable :p

Comment: Of course, how about this?

Comment: while i take a look at that, could you check something for me? Above the grid where the Contacts are in the experience profile it says "Search Results (#)", does the number match the amount of accounts you see?

Comment: The amount matches the result.

Answer (score 2):

Check the indexer is running and that there aren’t any errors in the indexer log. Check [this doc entry](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/xp-service-roles/indexer.html#check-application-logs) post for more info.

Also consider whether you are searching by PII data, which is not indexed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Experience Profile shows contacts from index. Not directly from DB.
Issue is definitely in indexing. It means that "sitecore_analytics_index"(I am not sure that it still have same name in Sitecore 9).
Have you tried to rebuild this certain index?

What I suggest to do:

1. Enable debug level of logging for indexing (crawling).
2. [Run "sitecore_analytics_index" index rebuild](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/rebuilding-the-sitecore-analytics-index) and check logs on any exceptions.

It will either give you a clue what happens, or you will be able to update question with more details.

UPDATE:
All mentioned above is relevant only for Sitecore 7.5-8.x

Comment: I would not rebuild the analytics as listed in this linked document.  Instead, you want to rebuild the reporting database.

Comment: @PeteNavarra I didn't understand your comment. List of contacts in Experience Profile is built using search index. If you have issue with index then nothing(or not all) will be shown. Samir has exact same symptoms. 
That is why I suggest him to take a look on indexing.

Experience Profile doesn't work with aggregated data at all. I didn't suggest Samir to rebuild the reporting database.

Comment: Rebuilding reporting index is **how** you rebuild the analytics index.  This is an old method that shouldn't be used.

Comment: Not anymore, indexing for XConnect in the 9 series is now completely independent to both aggregation (what the rebuild reporting database does) and content search (what other type of indexes in Sitecore use). See my answer for the link to more information on the XConnect indexer.

Comment: @eglasius Nice one, thank you, I didn't know it. Will update answer that it is relevant only for Sitecore 8.(Probably someone on Sitecore 8 will have this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Reporting such as Experience Profile is still aggregated data performed by the Processing pools.  That's still the same as before.  The difference between pre-9 with regards to contacts is that contact data is actually saved immediately instead of when session ends.  This means that contact data still needs to be processed at a regular interval and then it will show up in the list.  Take a look at the documentation on [Reporting](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/reporting/introduction.html), [Processing Architecture](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/architecture-overview/experience-platform/processing-architecture.html), [Interaction aggregation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/architecture-overview/experience-platform/processing-architecture.html) to see the sequence of events.

Comment: That actually changed for the 9 series. XConnect has its own indexer, completely independent to the other Sitecore indexes as well as to aggregation.